# Installing pycuda on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cuda, pycuda

I want to install [this package](http://sailfish.us.edu.pl/index.html) which uses pycuda on Ubuntu 14.04. (at this point version of pycuda don't matter)

After following instructions from [this page](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Linux/Ubuntu). I try to test the installation of pycuda with:

```
~/Downloads/pycuda-2015.1.3/test$ sudo python test_driver.py
```

which yields error:

```
ImportError: libcurand.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

During installation of pycuda i got warning:

> ```
> *** WARNING: nvcc not in path.
> *** May need to set CUDA_INC_DIR for installation to succeed.
> ```

But i can invoke

```
nvcc -V
```

and get

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
>   Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
>   Built on Thu_Mar_13_11:58:58_PDT_2014
>   Cuda compilation tools, release 6.0, V6.0.1

I have also tested CUDA installation with:

```
/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ sudo ./deviceQuery
```

and get

> deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 6.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 850M
>   Result = PASS

I have also set env_variables:

```
echo $PATH
echo $CUDA_ROOT
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which yields respectively:

> /usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>
> /usr/local/cuda
>
> /usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/X11.6/lib:/X11.5/lib:/uva/lib:/gnu/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

Preceding those commands with sudo gives the same result.

I have also tried installing pycuda with pip but received same behaviour with not being able to find nvcc.

Comment: libcurand.so.6.0 : Please try `$ locate libcurand.so.6.0` . I.e. there is a good chance that you have it ,  when you seemingly have built  the "/usr/local/cuda/" . ... https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/nvidia-cuda-toolkit ...

Comment: @KnudLarsen `$ locate libcurand.so.6.0` yields nothing. I don't understand why. Because there is file `libcurand.so.6.0.37 `and linkt to it `libcurand.so.6.0` at `/usr/local/cuda/lib`

Comment: The warning message clearly says to set the value of `CUDA_INC_DIR`. Did you?

Comment: @talonmies I didn't. But after your comment i set `export CUDA_INC_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include` and after removing directories from earlier installation I reruned it but to not avail. I still receive the same error about `libcurand.so.60`